# ASP.NET: Working in old domain but ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in new Domain

Tags: asp.net, blazor, microsoft-edge

I have created a Blazor Server side Application which is working perfectly fine when accessed on a Win 2012 Server in our old Domain, no matter in which Browser.

If I host it on a Win 2019 Server in the new Domain though, it's only working in Internet Explorer.
Edge displays the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. I did both of my tests from the same client which is located in the old Domain.

If I try to open it in Edge directly on the new Server, I receive another error: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

On both Servers it is running on Port 5001 (HTTPS)

Our Firewall department can't find any errors in the Logfiles.
Hope you guys have got an idea what might help.

Comment: You mentioned that only Internet Explorer work with new domain, have you test in chrome, or other browsers? Maybe you can try disabling the web proxy, or modify the DNS to see if that works.

Comment: Hi, in Firefox, Edge and CHrome it doesn't work, only in IE. There is no proxy in between, so I am a bit clueless what else I could do.

Comment: Hi. Is your problem solved? I am also facing the same problem. Let me know please.